# Freelance work doing sketchnoting - How do I start?

Tags: attracting-clients

I do sketchnotes as a hobby.  I'd like to do it professionally, as a freelancer to supplement my income.  I found some established people online - they are selling books, running their own companies etc.  So there seems to be work in this field.

Is there anyone here who actually does sketchnoting? If yes, how do I go about finding work?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any experience sketchnoting. But for any freelance business, the answer to "how do I find work" starts with:

- What kind of customers would need this product/service?
- How would those customers look for someone to perform this product/service (or will they have to be educated on sketchnoting first)?
- How can I make myself attract to them?

If I were you, I'd start coming up with a list of situations where sketchnoting could benefit a potential client. That will probably lead you to the type of customer who would buy this service, and hopefully will get you started on the other items as well.

Note: If your potential clients will need to be educated on sketchnoting, then it might not work very well as a part-time business - the client acquisition costs may be too high.